# Passing email verification link in Email Template, but it is not working

Tags: php

When a user signup, i am sending an email verification link through Brevo SMTP. User receives an email and click on verification link to verify his email. But the link doesn't work.
When clicked on the verification link, it simply redirects to login page and print the $to variable in input field of email. No console errors i have seen.
In the textarea i am passing and storing email verification content and URL that verifies the email. Here is url as well

```
Thank you for registering Vibes. We are registered company in India. Click on the following link to verify your account. https://dtotest.com/login.php?code=$numbers&&email=$to
```

But when the link is sent without embedding in email template and without SMTP it works.

My register.php code which is in INC folder

```
<?php 
 ob_start();
 if( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ){
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
 
 include_once 'include/config.php';
 $error = false;
 
 if ( isset($_POST['btn-signup']) ) {

 // if there's no error, continue to signup
  if( !$error ) {
   
    $numbers            =   mt_rand(0, 10000);
    $to                 =   $_POST['email'];
    $array_shortcodes   =   array();
    $send_mail          =   sendmail($to,$array_shortcodes,"register");
    
    if($send_mail){$msg=  "Send Email Confirm";}else{ $msg= "Sorry"; 
    }
```

now email-Template-edit.php code which is present in folder admin > email-Template-edit.php

```
<?php include("include/header.php");
include '../inc/register.php';
if($_POST['id']){

$details = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con,$_POST['details']);
$title   = $_POST['title'];
$type= $_POST['type'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$update  = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE emailtemplates SET title='".$title."',details='".$details."' WHERE id=".$id); 
if($update){

echo "<script>alert('Updated')</script>";
echo "<script>window.location='emailtemplateedit.php?id=".$id."&&type=".$type."' </script>";

    }


}

$type = $_GET['type'];
 ?>

<form class="theme-form theme-form-2 mega-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="mb-4 row align-items-center">
        <label class="control-label" for ="sender_title" >Email Subject Shortcode </label>
           <div>
            <span class="  shortcode">{first_name} </span>
            <span class="  shortcode">{last_name} </span>
            </div>
            </div>
<div class="mb-4 row align-items-center">
                                        <label class="control-label" for ="sender_title" >Short Codes</label>
                                        <?php
                                        $short_codes = array();
                                        if($type=="withdraw-approved" || $type=="withdraw-reject" || $type=="donation-received"){
                                            $short_codes[]  =   "{camping_title}";
                                            $short_codes[]  =   "{amount}";
                                        }
                                        if($type=="camping-approved" ||  $type=="camping-rejected"){
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{camping_title}";
                                        };  
                                        if($type=="thank-you"){
                                        $short_codes[] = "{camping_title}";
                                        $short_codes[] = "{amount}";
                                        }
                                        if($type=="bank-mail"){
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{camping_title}";
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{amount}";
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{bank_name}";
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{account_name}";
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{account_number}";
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{refrence_num}";
                                        }
                                        if($type=="forgot_password"){
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{reset_link}";
                                        }
                                        if($type=="contact"){
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{name}";
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{email}";
                                        $short_codes[]  = "{comments}";
                                        }
                                        ?>           
                                        <?php foreach($short_codes as $short_code)
                                        { ?>
                                        <span class="shortcode"><?php echo $short_code ?></span>
                                        <?php  } ?>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mb-4 row align-items-center">
                                        <label class="control-label" for ="sender_title" >Details</label>
                                        <textarea name="details" id="mytextarea" rows="10"></textarea>

                                    </div>

                                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo $template_detail['email_type'] ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $template_detail['id'] ?>">

                                    <button type="submit" name="updatesmtp" class="btn btn-info font-medium rounded-pill px-4">Update</button>
                                </form>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/36.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#mytextarea'))
        .then(editor => {
            // Set the value of CKEditor with PHP data
            editor.setData('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($emailContent, ENT_QUOTES); ?>');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
</script>
```

Finally login.php page PHP code which is doing verification

```
<?php 
$errMSG='';
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
$email = $_GET['email'];
$GetUsername = mysqli_query($con,
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userEmail`='$email' AND `rand_number`='".$_GET['code']."'");  
$NumRowsUser = mysqli_num_rows($GetUsername);

if($NumRowsUser > 0){
$CeateAccount = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `users` SET 
`rand_number`='1' WHERE `userEmail`='$email'");

if($CeateAccount){
$SuccType               = "success";
$_SESSION['message']    = 'You have successfully activated your account';
}

} 
}
?>
```

SMTP code

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';

require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

function sendmail($to,$array_shortcodes,$type){

global $con; 

 $smtp_query  =      mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM smtp_settings WHERE id=1") or die(mysqli_error($con));
 $smpt_detail          =      mysqli_fetch_assoc($smtp_query);
 $userquery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail='".$to."'");
 $usersinfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userquery);

$bodyHtml = $message;

  }

$bodyHtml = $message;

  }

  if($type=="register" ){

  

$bodyHtml = $message;

  }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, always use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: Another example of `mysqli_real_escape_string` failing to secure an app. You are only escaping one input

Comment: What is the "embedding in email template" done? That should be debugged as it sounds like you have identified that is where your issue is.

Comment: Embedding in email template means, i have let the user put the contents of email verification as he wants. Currently i am entering this in textarea for email content

Thank you for registering Vibes. We are registered company in India. Click on the following link to verify your account. https://dtotest.com/login.php?code=$numbers&&email=$to

Comment: So...when the link arrives in the email, does it contain the correct value? We cannot see it. And then when the request goes to login.php, does it receive those $_GET values successfully? And then what happens? What path does the code take? Have you actually done any debugging? Did the code get stored in the DB successfully so it can be matched? None of this is mentioned in the question, but instead there is a lot of code which seems to be largely irrelevant to the scenario. Make sure you always give a [mre] of the issue in your questions including _relevant_ code along with sample data

Comment: ADyon thanks for replying. 
The same url goes in address bar and no value gets printed. For example there is no value comes in url against $numbers and $to, and nothing gets updated when the url is clicked. 
But when i sent the same url without SMTP, then links works and values gets updated in the database as well. 
Just via SMTP it doesn't work.

Comment: Via smtp url in address bar comes like this after click

https://dototest.com/login.php?code=$numbers&&email=$to

and do nothing

but when sent without smpt, then it works and update the values

Comment: where you are integrating brevo smtp. where is that code? and where you are defining short codes?

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will be glad you took the time in the end.

Comment: `when sent without smpt`...it's not actually clear what this means. Sent where? And with what method instead?

Comment: Anyway it seems like the problem must be in the `sendmail` function, which is about the only thing you haven't shown us. Again, please provide a [mre] of the issue, ensuring that you show us everything that would be needed in order for us to reproduce the problem, or at least be able to see what the code is doing in each part of the process.

Comment: sendmail i have shown now. Sorry i forget

Comment: That can't be all of it. There's nothing there which would actually send an email. Also the function doesn't return anything, and its last `}` is missing. _Take your time_ and paste _all_ the relevant code, and _indent it properly_ so we can read it without squinting at where the different blocks are supposed to start and end. Help us to help you! Also you are never passing `$numbers` into that function, so how do you expect it to be used in the email body??

Comment: As Adyson also said, provide the complete code and minimal reproducible example. You didn't send smtp code where smtp and sendmail was defined. Without that it is not possible to debug and find the issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do this in SMTP code

```
$bodyHtml = $message;

  }

if($type=="register" ){
 
$message = str_replace('$numbers',$array_shortcodes['code'],$message);
$message = str_replace('$to',$array_shortcodes['email'],$message);
$bodyHtml = $message;

  }
```

do this in Register code

```
if( !$error ) {
   
  $numbers            =  mt_rand(0, 10000);
    $to                 = $_POST['email'];
  $array_shortcodes   = array("code"=>$numbers,"email"=>$to);
    $subject            = sendmail($to,$array_shortcodes,"register");
    if($send_mail) 
  {$msg =  "Send Email Confirm";}
  else{ $msg= "Sorry";
    }
```

no need to change anything else. Give it a test, it should work

Comment: applying and testing

Comment: How does this work? The `mt_rand` value isn't being written anywhere so it can't validate/verify a user

Comment: `$numbers` isn't passed to the sendmail function. Nor is it seemingly saved into the `users` table at any point. So it's unclear how this could possibly be working, or why the answer has been accepted.

Comment: And if anything, the formatting and readability here is even worse than in the OP's original code. Could be downvoted on presentation alone. A quick [edit] would do no harm.

Comment: $numbers are passed here.
array_shortcodes   = array("code"=>$numbers,"email"=>$to);
and if you look into login code, rand_number is written as well.

Comment: In the login code rand_number is bring read _from_ the database, but nowhere in anything we've seen is it being inserted _into_ the database after it was generated

Comment: Also `$message` is undefined in the sendmail function  at the point it is passed into str_replace